# Python: converting numpy.float64 to float

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new to programming. I am trying to write a program for the calibration of a force sensor with jupyter notebook.

The program performs a linear regression and gives 4 values as output. I would like to store those in a file that can be used to analyze data in a different notebook later. To that end, I want to store the variables in a dictionary. Is there a way to create the dictionary and pass only the keys without explicitely stating the value? The way I tried it looks like i pass the keys and only the values are returned when I print it. When I try to apply .iteritems() to my dictionary, the error message is:

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'iteritems

My second problem is that my values are of the type np.float64.
When trying to write my dictionary to a json file, I get the error message:

> TypeError: {-0.12445078556831463, -46.182468927670612,
>   -0.095329810791781794, -13.515569864414863} is not JSON serializable

I have looked into a lot of solutions for converting the values to float, but I couldn't get them to work for me so far.

The part of my code that I am talking about is:

```
dictResults = {KeyA, KeyB, KeyC, KeyD}
filename1 = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
with open(filename1 + '.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(dictResults, f)
f.close()
```

Comment: You are not creating a dictionary, you are creating a set. casting to native Python floats: `float(KeyA)`. Building a dict from keys: `dict.fromkeys(key_list)` will use None for all values

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I solved my dictionary problem by `dictResults = ['KeyA' : KeyA,...]`. It was kindof obvious, I just didn't see it... `float(KeyA)` won't work in my program, unfortunately. When I do `type(KeyA)` afterwards, I still get "numpy.float64" as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you actually assigning the float back to KeyA? As in `KeyA = float(KeyA)`?

Comment: No, that was the mistake I was making. Thanks again!